# How to display several features of a vector in Open Layers?

Tags: openlayers

I am building a web map, with some layers imported from a Geoserver. I have already transformed them into a vector JSON. I want to display all the features of the geometries outside of the map in an HTML panel.

I just could do this with only one feature 'obra_nro' that I took with the method .get. You can see the code that I am using below.

But, I still couldn't find a way to display the rest of the features.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
        hitTolerance:1  ///// Precision del puntero del mouse para seleccionar
    });
olMap.getInteractions().extend([selectInteraction]);

    var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {
        var features = [];
        olMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        features.push(feature);
        });
        var container = document.getElementById('description');
        if (features.length > 0) {
        var info = [];
        for (var i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; ++i) {
        info.push(features[i].get('obra_nro'));
        }
        container.innerHTML = info.join(', ') || '(unknown)';
        } else {
        container.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        }   
    };

    olMap.on('click' , function(evt) {
        var pixel = evt.pixel;
        displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent with the view extent on each of your vector sources, for example

```
var features = [];
olMap.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
  var source = layer.getSource();
  if (source && source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent) {
    source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(olMap.getView().calculateExtent(), function(feature) {
      features.push(feature);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With a friend, we found a reasonable solution to the problem. We keep the original function, but we modified the "if" section.

```
var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
        hitTolerance:1  ///// Precision del puntero del mouse para seleccionar
    });
    olMap.addInteraction(selectInteraction);

    olMap.on('singleclick', function(e) {
        var feature = olMap.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature) {
            return feature;
        });
        var infoElement = document.getElementById('description');
        var html = "";
        if(feature){
            html += feature.get('obra_nro')+"</br>";
            html += feature.get('contratist')+"</br>";
            html += feature.get('mes1')+"</br>";
            html += feature.get('mes2')+"</br>";
            html += feature.get('mes3')+"</br>";
            html += feature.get('mes4')+"</br>";
        }
        infoElement.innerHTML = html;
    });
```